# Is it possible to make predictions with a keras/TensorFlow model without downloading TensorFlow and all its dependancies?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to use a custom keras model I trained with tensorflow-gpu on my desktop with Python on a mobile phone (Android), however I need to run it with Python on the phone as well. I looked up TensorFlow Lite, however that appears to be written for Java.

Is there any lite (Python) version of TensorFlow, some kind of barebones package that's just set up for making predictions from a TensorFlow/keras model file? I'm trying to focus on saving space, so a solution under 50mb would be desired.

Thanks

Comment: If you wish to run the model on an Android device, you can use TensorFlow Lite as Android supports Java and Kotlin. Otherwise, you can't run Python ( so easily ) on an Android device.

Comment: I already have a project I'm working on that's fully written with Python and C++ running on Android, but I'm only really familiar with Python. I need the data in the Python scripts that are already written. Disregarding the Android part of this, is there any way to run a TensorFlow model without TensowFlow itself?

Comment: Have you considered the possibility of hosting the model somewhere (GCP ML-Engine or similar) and making http calls from the device for the predictions? Accept it's not a solution for every use-case but if acceptable for your case may be simpler to implement

Comment: Can you elaborate on the requirement to run it with python? Otherwise, you might want to look at TF Serving. No need to run TF locally that way at all.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I do need to run it locally, as it will be controlling the braking and gas commands for a car over CAN bus, and over the internet for this isn't feasible. I'm working with openpilot, which is a largely Python-based project running on an Android phone. Perhaps I picked the wrong machine learning tool to train with. Is there another tool I could use with a smaller footprint that works with python?

Answer (score 1):

[TensorFlow Serving](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide/serving) was built for the specific purpose of serving pre-trained models. I'm not sure if it runs (or how difficult to make it run) on Android or what it's compiled footprint is, if it's less than 50MB. If you can make it work, please do report back here!